# How to Print BarCode on "TSC TTP-244 Pro " printer's stickers from SSRS reports

Tags: reporting-services

I want to print bar code from SSRS reports to stickers,Please let me know how can i adjust my setting to print Bar Code on printer's label in an efficiently manners.Actually i do not know how i can adjust my setting,Any one who have done this kind of work Please help, i will be highly appreciate.

Comment: `@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Id)`

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation. And your question needs to include the code, not images of it

Comment: Also, do not post images of code. Post relevant code in the question with proper formatting.

Comment: Thanks Shyju actually i am new at stack-overflow

Answer (score 0):

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Id)
```